# How to specify where a Python FMX GUI Form opens?

Tags: python, user-interface, firemonkey, centering

I'm creating a `Form` using [DelphiFMX GUI library for Python](https://github.com/Embarcadero/DelphiFMX4Python) and I would like to choose a specific location where the Form should open. Here's the code that I use to create my Form:

```
from delphifmx import *

class frmMain(Form):
    def __init__(self, owner):
        self.Caption = 'My Form'
        self.Width = 1000
        self.Height = 500

def main():
    Application.Initialize()
    Application.Title = "My Application"
    Application.MainForm = frmMain(Application)
    Application.MainForm.Show()
    Application.Run()
    Application.MainForm.Destroy()

main()
```

Are there any built-in functions, procedures, or properties that I can use to change the position of the Form?

For some of my forms, I want them to be centered and for others, I want to set a custom X and Y coordinate.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's a built-in `Position` property on every `Form` as well as `Left` and `Top` properties. You can add the following line of code to center your `Form` when it starts:

```
self.Position = "ScreenCenter"
```

Some of the other options you have in the `Position` property are:

[image: FireMonkey Form Position Property]

When you set the `Position` to `Designed`, then you can specify custom `Left` and `Top` values for it:

```
self.Position = "Designed"
self.Top = 420
self.Left = 69
```

`Top` is the `Y coordinate` and `Left` is the `X coordinate.